# How do I programmatically add child views to an Ember view at specific DOM selectors?

Tags: ember.js

I have a view that uses a 3rd party library to render additional DOM elements in the didInsertElement hook. After these new elements are added, I need to add some child views inside them, so that they can render dynamic data.

Here's what I tried:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    create3rdPartyDomElements();
    var element = this.$('someSelector');
    childView = this.createChildView(App.SomeViewClass, attributesDict);
    childView.appendTo(element);
  }
});
```

(jsbin: http://jsbin.com/idoyic/3)

This renders my views as expected, but gives the following assertion error with Ember RC 7: "You cannot append to an existing Ember.View. Consider using Ember.ContainerView instead."

I have tried extending ContainerView, as advised [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/manually-managing-view-hierarchy/) and that works, but I have no way of inserting the child views at specific DOM selectors. It just inserts the child views at the beginning of the parent view.

Can someone please help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want to use bindings or some other ember tecnology in that generated dom? Or is just something visual, and it isn't important? What is your third party libray?

Comment: It's http://codemirror.net/ and yes - I need to use bindings in the generated dom. Not to sync the code in the editor, but to add extra visual widgets to the editor.

Comment: This hack was suggested on IRC, but it seems to create some ugly side effects after switching through a couple of routes: http://jsbin.com/owepeh/1

Comment: nice @AndreiSoare that works, however, we adding the run.next code ? it works without it

Comment: Yeah, it seems to work without run.next. But as I said, it introduces some side effects: when leaving the route and entering it again, other issues start to appear :-s

Comment: wouldn't it be good to just render those views you want to append to '#test' under a hidden div, and then with jquery, append it to '#test' ? I mean, in IRC people suggested a hack for that, and I read here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1190 that the error is fine, so  maybe there's no a good way to do it in ember, why not giving a try to jquery or whatever you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render child views into parent view's hidden div, and then detach and append them to arbitrary DOM elements in `didInsertElement` hook.

http://jsbin.com/qaqome/1/

For related issue (components instead of views) see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165802/appending-ember-component-to-a-dom-element-not-managed-by-ember).

Answer (score 4):

This is how I created:

An implementation where you have the main view, in that case codemirror, in the middle. And it's possible add more views, in the top or bottom.

```
App.EditorView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'editor-view',
  topView: Ember.ContainerView.extend(),
  bottomView: Ember.ContainerView.extend(),
  CodeMirrorView: Ember.TextArea.extend({  
    didInsertElement: function() {      
      this.codeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(this.get('element'));                  
    }
  })
});
```

The template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="editor-view">
  {{view view.topView viewName="topViewInstance"}}
  {{view view.CodeMirrorView}}
  {{view view.bottomView viewName="bottomViewInstance"}}
</script>
```

A view to represent a custom component:

```
App.MyComponent = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'click-here',
  message: null,
  click: function() {
    alert(this.get('message'));
  }
});
```

The implementation:

```
App.MyEditorView = App.EditorView.extend({  
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this._super();
    this.get('topViewInstance').pushObject(App.MyComponent.create({ message: "Hello" }));

    this.get('bottomViewInstance').pushObject(App.MyComponent.create({ message: "World" }));
  }
});
```

With this is possible to create a new instance, or extend `App.EditorView` and insert more views in top or bottom. Because the `topView` and `bottomView` are `Ember.ContainerView`s, all views added will have the bindings, events, and other ember features.

Give a look in that jsbin to see it working http://jsbin.com/ucanam/686/edit

Comment: Hi Marcio - thanks for the thorough answer. It's not exactly what I had in mind, since I want to be able to add views to the DOM generated by CodeMirror.fromTextArea(). That's why I am using this.$('someSelector') in my code. If you look here http://codemirror.net/demo/widget.html you will see some widgets added inside the editor, between the lines. I want to add widgets like those, rendered by Ember views.

Comment: Hmm now I understand. No problem, when I have some time I will check this. Because I didn't have created a widget in codemirror. I don't know to answer at first glance.

Comment: No worries. I avoided mentioning codemirror because I was looking for a generic solution to this problem: how can I programmatically add child views to views at specific html elements, not just at the beginning / end of the parent views?

Answer (score 0):

try adding a property in your view, something like this:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  childViewsContainer: Em.ContainerView.create({}),
  didInsertElement: function() {
    create3rdPartyDomElements();
    var element = this.$('someSelector');
    childViewsContainer.createChildView(App.SomeViewClass, attributesDict);
    childView.appendTo(element);
  }
});
```

then, you can access your childViewsContainer and do what ever you want with it

Comment: This won't work, it gives the same error and another deprecation warning: Using the defaultContainer is no longer supported. [defaultContainer#lookup] see: http://git.io/EKPpnA

Comment: I have created 2 jsbins, one with my initial attempt and one with your suggestion. Feel free to play around: http://jsbin.com/idoyic/3 and http://jsbin.com/irifes/2