# Appending Ember Component to a DOM element not managed by Ember

Tags: ember.js

I would like to append an Ember Component `ComponentB` to a DOM element which is generated by some non-Ember UI library on `didInsertElement` of `ComponentA`, resulting in something like

```
<div class='ember-view component-a'>
   <div class='i-know-nothing-of-ember'>
      <div class='ember-view component-b'></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am aware of `appendTo(element)` method, however it fails with assertion

> You cannot append to an existing Ember.View. Consider using Ember.ContainerView instead.

I also tried calling `createElement` on component B and then appending it to DOM via jQuery - which kind of works, however in the end it fails with error

> Cannot set property '_elementInserted' of null

See http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cofebo/2/

What is the *proper* way to achieve the above; if possible actions and other behaviours should be as if `i-know-nothing-of-ember` would be generated by Component A template.

Comment: Just to additionally clarify my use-case: Component A is wrapping `slickgrid`, which is generated on `didInsertElement`. `slickgrid` exposes div `topPane` which can be used to append additional content bellow column headers. I would like to nest `Component B` in this div.

Comment: Wrapping `Component B` creation and appending to div into `Run.next` successfully appends component without error, however it still seems more of a hack...Updated [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/cofebo/4/)

Comment: Updated [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/cofebo/5/) according to Approach 3 in @melc answer.

Comment: I've solved a problem similar to this using Ember Wormhole https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-wormhole

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using the container to lookup the component and append it anywhere whenever you need to.

**Approach 1 -  retrieve container within route**

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/libipazavu/1/edit?html,js,output

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  setupController:function(controller,model){
    controller.set("container",this.container);
  }
});

App.IndexView = Em.View.extend({

  appendNonEmberUILibrary:function(){
    callNonEmberUILibrary();
    var componentB = this.get("controller.container").lookup("component:component-b");
    componentB.appendTo(".non-ember-ui");
  }.on("didInsertElement")
});

App.ComponentBComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  layoutName:"components/component-b",
  prop1:"test-option-1"
});


function callNonEmberUILibrary(){
  $("body").append("<div class='non-ember-ui' style='border:1px solid;'>element from non-ember ui lib</div>");
}
```

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
    <h3>Adding Ember Component to non-Ember DOM Element using <u><i>container</i></u></h3>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/component-b">
  <br/>
  <div style="border:1px dashed #F5664D">
  This is componentB ->  {{prop1}}
  </div>
  <br/>
  </script>
```

**Approach 2 -  retrieve container within an initializer**

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hijedowacu/1/edit?html,js,output

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.initializer({
  name:"main",
  initialize:function(container,application){
     application.register('main:compB', container.lookup("component:component-b"), { instantiate: false });
     application.inject("controller:index","theComponentB","main:compB");
  }
});

App.IndexView = Em.View.extend({

  appendNonEmberUILibrary:function(){
    callNonEmberUILibrary();
    var componentB = this.get("controller.theComponentB");
    componentB.appendTo(".non-ember-ui");
  }.on("didInsertElement")
});

App.ComponentBComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  layoutName:"components/component-b",
  prop1:"test-option-1"
});


function callNonEmberUILibrary(){
  $("body").append("<div class='non-ember-ui' style='border:1px solid;'>element from non-ember ui lib</div>");
}
```

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
    <h3>Adding Ember Component to non-Ember DOM Element using <u><i>container</i></u></h3>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/component-b">
  <br/>
  <div style="border:1px dashed #F5664D">
  This is componentB ->  {{prop1}}
  </div>
  <br/>
  </script>
```

---

**Approach3 - reallocate added component with jquery (update from comments)**

Alternatively you could just add the `component-b` in the template as non visible and within `didInsertElement` you could reallocate and display it wherever required using jquery.

example http://jsbin.com/maginovexa/1/edit?html,js,output

**js**

```
App.IndexView = Em.View.extend({
  prop2:"prop-from-index-view",
  appendNonEmberUILibrary:function(){
    callNonEmberUILibrary();
    //var componentB = this.get("controller.container").lookup("component:component-b");
    //componentB.appendTo(".non-ember-ui");
    var componentBDOM = this.get("componentB").$().detach();
    $(".non-ember-ui").append(componentBDOM);
  }.on("didInsertElement"),
  click:function(){this.set("prop2",Date.now());}
});

App.ComponentBComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  layoutName:"components/component-b",
  prop1:"test-option-1"
});


function callNonEmberUILibrary(){
  $(".inner").append("<div class='non-ember-ui' style='border:1px solid;'>element from non-ember ui lib</div>");
}
```

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
    <h3>Adding Ember Component to non-Ember DOM Element using <u><i>container</i></u></h3>
    <div class='inner'></div>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  this is index (click here to change prop2 of component)
  <div style="display:none">
    {{component-b prop2=view.prop2 viewName="componentB"}}
    </div>


  </script>
....
```

This is a fully working solution for reallocating an ember controlled element to a non-ember element that is within an ember view, as requested by Simon Jesenko (the op).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however the suggested approaches do not work in my case - non-ember UI library is appending to the DOM within ember view, thus component.attachTo call fails. I have updated your examples with my scenario:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xiciji/1/
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hifuge/1/

Comment: Third approach (adding `component-b` to template as nonvisible and the reallocating) should probably work, however it does seem a bit 'hackish' - not sure if actions would propagate properly from `component-b`, etc.

Comment: @SimonJesenko i didn't notice that the non-ember element was within an ember view, so in that case to place something within that dom element the approach that i suggest is the third one! for example http://jsbin.com/maginovexa/1/edit?html,js,output  , i have used this approach plenty of times to reallocate components/views in places where a containerview is not available/possible but within the same parent view. The properties as well as the actions do work fine.

Comment: Great, thanks, that seems to do it! I have updated my initial JsBin to suggested approach: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cofebo/5/)

Comment: It would be probably best for future reference if you just include Approach  3 in the answer...

Comment: @SimonJesenko great !

Comment: A better alternative to the first two options is `Ember.getOwner(this).factoryFor('component:myComponent').create()`.  Unfortunately it still doesn't work if the element you're attempting to `appendTo` _"has an ancestor element that is associated with an Ember view"_

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the run loop? Like this,

```
//after comp.createElement();

parent = this;

Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', this, function() {

  parent.$('.i-know-nothing-of-ember').append($(comp.element));

});
```